# Relationship filtering by category

Tags: categories, relationships

*Echoing post from http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/236223/ as suspected error in user documentation.*

Looking at the documentation for the new relationships functionality it says filtering by category is supported (3rd paragraph of introduction): http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/relationships.html#accessing-parents

However this is not listed as one of the supporting parameters under http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/relationships.html#id9 and does not seem to work when I try something along the lines of the following:

{parents field="minutes_partner" category="20"}
{parents:title}
{/parents}

Anyone know if category filtering supported in relationships and if so how can I achieve this without writing some crazy custom query or coding a plugin?

Cole

Comment: I think in that 3rd paragraph they might be referring to the control panel > publish form. There doesn't appear to be a category parameter for the parents tag pair.

Answer (score 1):

Just had this precise problem.

Rummaged around and did a *little* hack to make this work.

Open this file

`/system/expressionengine/libraries/relationship_parser/Parser.php`

Look for:

`$rows[$entry_id] = $data;`

If you simply move this line to be the last line inside the foreach loop that starts

`foreach ($entry_ids as $entry_id)`

Then it works.

Your script may differ slightly, but my line moved from line #475 to line #520

Comment: This solved the problem for me and I believe this is a bug so I filed a report here: https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/20012

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar issue recently and I used an IF statement to solve the problem for me. Might help with others who find this page looking for similar answers.

To use the OP's example:

Trying to get the following to work:

```
{parents field="minutes_partner" category="20"} {parents:title} {/parents}
```

How I got around it:

```
{parents field="minutes_partner"}
   {if "{parents:categories}{category_id}{/parents:categories}"=="20"}
      {parents:title}
   {/if}
{/parents}
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

This hack does work for the parent output but the standard output does not work now. Any ideas?

Not working...

{campus}
    {campus:title}
{/campus}